# I cannot add footnotes in my document using \footnote

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing, footnotes, appendices

When I try and add a footnote to my section title (although i have the same issue when adding to the main
body of text) using

`\section{TITLE \protect\footnote{footnote here with \cite{citation}}}`

I get **TITLE[? ]** in my compiled document with no footnote.

The code/set-up that I'm working with is:

```
%%%%% Document Setup %%%%%%%%

\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn, nofootinbib]{revtex4}    


\usepackage{times}                          
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.85cm, right=1.85cm,top=1.85cm, bottom=1.85cm]{geometry}       

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}                      


\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,epsfig,ulem}  
\usepackage{amsmath}                        

\usepackage{etoolbox}                       

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{(}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{)}{}{}{}
\renewcommand\Dated@name{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}                           
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        

\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}        


%%%%% Document %%%%%  
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{ref01}

\end{thebibliography} 

\newpage

\section*{Appendix}



\end{document}
```

How can I get my footnote to BE a footnote at the bottom of the Page?
Also, with the citation, my references section is before the section I want to add a footnote to (The Appendix), so will this make a difference?

I have tried adding the footnote with and without the citation in the section title and in the main body of the text with no success

**EDIT**
I have added `nofootinbib` to the document class, and now I get a footnote number, but the footnote does not appear at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This kind of footnote is a feature of the `revtex4` class. If you want more effective help you need to provide an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't get an error, if I place a `\footnote` (without `\cite`) in the body text. Inside a `\section` command, it seems indeed not to work.

Comment: @Ivan Thankyou so much I think I have it now!

Answer (score 2):

I changed the document class from its original form:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4}
```

to

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn, nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
```

which allows me to add footnotes in both the section title and the main body of the text. I cannot cite within the footnote in the section title but I can cite within the footnote in the main body of the text.